# When will Custom buttons with Javascript actions be supported in Lightning experience?

Tags: community, lightning-experience

In the company that I work we all are keen to start using lightning experience but according to Salesforce (Winter 16') custom buttons with actions (like OnClick Javascript buttons) are not yet supported in lightning experience. Does anyone know when this feature will be supported?

Lightning experience is a great product but we can't use it because these actions are not supported yet. When they released Winter 16 they didn't have a date for this. Does anyone know something about this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question .I don't think this question will get answered on this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. According to several Salesforce sources like e.g. [Deciding If Lightning Experience Is Right for You](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme) it's not supported as of now. You can vote for this particular feature [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM), where it is currently "UNDER PM REVIEW".

Comment: Thanks four your answer. Is still not supported and there is no possible date yet.

Answer (score 1):

To get addressed for this query, You should post/visit Ideas on Success community of salesforce.

You can vote on this idea to keep a track on progress.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cGX8AAM